# How big is a LEGO torso in Microsoft Paint

Tags: software, customization, stickers

I am trying to print decals, but I don't know how the size of the torso or any other parts are supposed to scale in my Microsoft Paint.

Comment: Assuming you have Microsoft Paint, you can use Microsoft word to size your creation to match the torso size. Make sure your original decal is cropped to remove all whitespace first, then resize and print it in Word.

Answer (score 4):

The size won't matter in Paint, what will matter is the resolution of your printer.

For example, if you want to print 1 inch by 1 inch, and your printer is 800 DPI, then you need an 800x800 image.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjwzcqq4OjLAhUNwGMKHT8OCPgQFggsMAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.eurobricks.com%2Fforum%2Findex.php%3Fshowtopic%3D25534&usg=AFQjCNGR0GizfISb60b4U0B67G_BCYTubg&sig2=pVM42X8QMMKGCqBRScM28g) for decal specs.

But honestly, the issue is mostly about your program of choice. You can't resize in anything but pixels, and as the other responder said, your dpi really means the entire problem, because each dot is a pixel, and it can print *waaay* off. There is a free, proven-safe program (I have it on all my school computers too,) called Paint.net, which allows you to choose your size in centimeters/inches for your graphic. Now all you have to do is measure your torso, and put the art at normal size onto your paper.

In Microsoft Paint? Sorry, man. It just won't cut it. To use a measure, you need to have a program that understands a measurement.